# Metro Bundler error in installing own npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have created this npm package. After installing it in another app and running it, I get the error:

```
Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error
```

This happens even if the project is a newly initialised one. What is wrong in my npm package?

Comment: check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17685

Comment: @SantoshSharma This issue is only happening when I install my npm package, not in other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because in your index.js file you have

```
import App from "./src/App";
```

but there is no such file in your repo.

Comment: In the `package.json`, the `main` attribute is directed to `src/index.js`. Removing the top level `index.js` maakes no difference.

Comment: I think you need to add module.exports = Keyboard; in the end of your index.js file also in order to have access to it through your app

Comment: I have already added `export default` to the class at the end.

Comment: yes and you can use it in the repo, but  not as a mobule by your app after installing it with npm